# Dealing with Categories in documents for elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, categories

Been wrestling with this a while and need some help.

I have a document array in PHP that looks something like this

```
array("title"=>"some title",  
      "description" => "Short description",
      "categories" => array ( array("id" => "1", "name" => "category 1"),
                              array("id" => "5", "name" => "category 5"),
                              array("id" => "55", "name" => "category 55"),
                             )
);
```

So basically I have a document that has many categories assigned.  My ultimate aim with this is to return all documents that contain a specific category by ID.

I have setup mappings, and the documents are being index OK.  I have tried both "nested" type of mapping for category, no mapping at all, and "lists" type but that did not work at all with the error on creation of the mappings.

sample of how I set up "lists"

```
array(
    '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(                    
        'title' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        ),            
        'description' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        ),            
        'categories' => array(
            "type" => "lists",
            "properties"=> array(
                    "id" => array("type"=> "integer" ),
                    "name" => array( "type"=> "string" ),
                ),
        ),

    )
    );
```

And for completeness, how I set it up as "nested"

```
array(
    '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(                    
        'title' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        ),            
        'description' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        ),            
        'categories' => array(
            "type" => "nested",
            "properties"=> array(
                    "id" => array("type"=> "integer" ),
                    "name" => array( "type"=> "string" ),
                ),
        ),

    )
    );
```

When trying to make a search against nested mappings, it tells me

```
 QueryParsingException:  [nested] nested object under path [categories] is not of nested type
```

When trying to make a nested search against an un mapped set of categories (defaulting to what the system finds) it also returns the same error as above.

My questions are:

1. what mapping should I setup for these array of categories ?
2. Given a  "match_all" query, what filter (and how) should I use to get a single category?

so much thanks in advance for anyone who even takes the time to read this, let alone answer. I'm really hopeful that you can help.

Comment: Given the error you get for "nested", I suggest taking out the PHP from the equation and use curl or Marvel's Sense interface to do the mapping directly in ES and perform the test queries there as well. After you establish which mapping and which query works, try to "translate" everything in PHP.

Comment: I'll give that a go.  I have been using the  official API so far, so it would be a shame to have to also use curl/json as well as that.  BUT if that gets it working, then its the key I need.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks again for the advise.  it was the right choice. between that and looking at the logs each time, I debugged it, and yes, removed all of my human error. 

All the best and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple.  I had misread the documentation and has added an extra object type into my mapping requests that did not need to be there.

```
        'categories' => array(
        "type" => "lists",
        "properties"=> array(
                "id" => array("type"=> "integer" ),
                "name" => array( "type"=> "string" ),
            ),
    ),
```

should have been

```
        'categories' => array(          
        "properties"=> array(
                "id" => array("type"=> "integer" ),
                "name" => array( "type"=> "string" ),
            ),
    ),
```

The array type does not need to be defined as a type, it is assumed to be an array. Once removed, it loads the mapping properly.

Now on to searching....